# Auto fill RadComboBox not working in IE 9

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have used the following code to create a Drop-down list with auto fill feature, but it's not working in IE 9 and IE 10.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" Width="590px"
    Height="140px" AllowCustomText="false"
    MarkFirstMatch="true" AutoCompleteSeparator=";"
    EmptyMessage="Type an E-mail" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    DataTextField="DSG_NAME" OnItemDataBound="RadComboBox1_ItemDataBound">
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: What version you use? Is is working on other explorers?

Comment: @kostas version 2008.1.415.35

Yes Its working IE 8 and firefox

Comment: I think but i am not sure, is not support ie 9 and 10.